# how to compress and upload High qualilty video to the server

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

uploading HDvideo to the server using ASIFormDataRequest.
but it taking long time to upload.

my code is

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

if (movieUrl != Nil) {
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieUrl];
[request addData:videoData withFileName:[movieUrl lastPathComponent] andContentType:@"audio/mp4" forKey:@"video"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
//
[request setTimeOutSeconds:600];

[request setDelegate:self];
//
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:progressView];

[request startSynchronous];
```

where movieurl is url return from imagepickerdidfinish

```
 movieUrl = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are doing All of this synchronously which means your interface is blocked and seem unresponsive. I would recommend using asynchronous connection which will be way more responsive, executing on a separate thread and not blocking the main thread. Use:

```
[request startAsynchronous]
```

Comment: how to compressed the video.